# Creating a fraction list array in a class | C++

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I need help creating a fractionlist array in a class.
So lets say I already have a fraction class with private: numerator and denom.

So what I'm suppose to do within this fractionlist class is

1. I should be able to read a file that contains a list like this.
   " 22 51 3 5 11 43 34 54 " with the first being a numerator and the second being a denom and so on. So it has 4 fractions. I want those 4 fractions to be stored in the array that is a private member. The max is 20 fractions.
2. I should be able to print to an output file or standard output the following:
   a) All the fractions.  b)Sum of all the fractions in fraction form (Example: numerator: 55, denominator: 82)

What I really just want to know is what should my private data members be?

here is what I have.

```
class Fractionlist
{
Private:
    Fractionlist [] Max;
    const static int MaxFraction = 30;

}
```

Which private member functions to set up so I do what is asked. So basically I need the the data members that would allow me to input the fractions.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to write a fraction class, and store fractions in any one of the standard library containers? Also, the code you are showing is not C++.

Comment: Since you know that there are 4 fractions per list, just use `Fractionlist Max[4]`

Comment: Well the fractionlist is done in a different .h, all of them are in different files like .cpp/.h. I don't know, that is my assignment, create a Fractionlist class in different .h file.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on juanchopanza's comment, you might want to create a class similar to this one:

```
class MyFraction
{
public:
    MyFraction(int numerator, int denominator)
    {
        _numerator = numerator;
        _denominator = denominator;
    }

    void Print()
    {
        // ...
    }

private:
    int _numerator;
    int _denominator;
};
```

Then read the numbers from the file and store them in a vector

```
std::vector<MyFraction> fractionList;
```

Finally, implement two functions

```
void PrintFractions(std::vector<MyFraction> fractionList);
MyFraction SumFractions(std::vector<MyFraction> fractionList);
```

To print and sum the contents of the vector, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

From what you've described I would be tempted to go with something like this:

```
class Fraction
{
    int numerator;
    int denominator;
};

class Fractionlist
{
    const static int MaxFraction = 20;

    int number_of_fractions; // how many are in the array?

private:
    Fraction list[MaxFraction]; // array of Fraction objects

public:
    Fractionlist(): number_of_fractions(0) {} // list is empty when created

    bool add(const Fraction& f) { /* add fraction return false if too may */ }
    Fraction sum() { /* add up fractions and return */ }
};
```

Assuming you can't use standard library containers.